# SQL Top 10 Totals

Tags: sql-server-2008

How do I select the top 10 descending totals from a column (Amount) based on another column (ID)?

This is what I'd like my desired results to look like:

```
(Top 1)
Row 1: ID: 9, Amount: 10, Total: 15
Row 2: ID: 9, Amount: 5, Total: 15

(Top 2)
Row 3: ID: 500, Amount: 14, Total: 14

(Top 3)
Row 4: ID: 27, Amount: 3, Total: 9
Row 5: ID: 27, Amount: 3, Total: 9
Row 6: ID: 27, Amount: 3, Total: 9 etc.
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from t where id in 
(select top 10 id from t group by id order by sum(Amount) desc)
```

if you need the final results to be ordered by sum(Amount) here is a query:

```
select t.*,t2.sum_amount from t 
inner join (select top 10 id,sum(Amount) as sum_amount 
                 from t 
              group by id 
              order by sum(Amount) desc) t2
        on (t.Id = t2.id)
order by t2.Sum_amount desc ,id
```

Comment: I think you are missing an order by clause.. How will order the final result?

Comment: @JoeGJoseph Yes you can also add `ORDER BY id` to order results

Comment: @JoeGJoseph: I've added ordered version into the answer.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
;with cte as
    (select *,
     row_number() over(partition by ID order by Amount desc) as row_num
     from  your_table),
 cte1 as(
    select ID,SUM( Amount) as Total
    from   your_table
    group  by ID)
select top 10 c.ID,C.Amount,c1.Total
from cte c join cte1 c1
on c.ID=c1.ID
order by C1.Total desc
```

## [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5abcb/1)

Answer (score 0):

`select Row, ID, Amount, Total
from
(
  select Row, ID, Amount, Total
    ,rank() over (order by Total desc) as Rank
  from t1
) rt
where Rank between 1 and 10`